# What other mythologies' figures are represented in SG1 aside from Norse and Egyptian pantheons?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

For most part, it seems that the Asgard have the names of (and presumably interacted with humans in the past as) Norse pantheon; whereas Goa'uld impersonated Ancient Egyptian pantheon.

Were there any cases when either of the two (or any other aliens) represented gods outside Norse and Egyptian (but actual real-world) Earth myths?

Comment: I don't think the other races impersonated ancient earth pantheon, rather the pantheon followed the alien races.  Ancient humans not able to understanding what they were seeing/experiencing became the religion/folk lore.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are a considerable number of [Goa'uld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goa%27uld_characters_in_Stargate) (and other alien) characters in Stargate that represent figures from a range of Earth mythologies;

- **Ba'al, Moloc, and Qetesh** represent *Canaanite* gods
- **Cronus, Ares, Nerus, Athena, Pelops and Thanos (aka Thanatos)** represent *Greek* gods
- **Nirrti and Kali** represent *Hindu* deities
- **Lord Yu** represents a *Chinese* emperor (interestingly not considered a god in Chinese mythos)
- **Amaterasu** represents a *Japanese* god
- **Camulus and Morrigan** represent *Celtic* gods
- **Olokun** represents a *Yoruba* god
- **Ishkur** and **Marduk** represent *Messopotamian* gods
- **Svarog** represents a *Slavic* god
- **Telchak (also known as Chaac) and Zipacna** represent *Mayan* gods
- **Tiamat** (a Goa'uld) and **Omoroca** (an Ohne) represent *Babylonian* gods
- **Sokar (Satan)** represents a figure from Christianity (h/t to @Greenstone Walker)
- **Oma Desala** (an ancient) is a literal translation of Mother Nature (according to Daniel) from Buddhist mythos.
- **Merlin** (an ancient) represents a figure from Arthurian legend.

Comment: Very comprehensive list  across a wide range of myths, well done.

Comment: We shouldn't forget the various ascended beings which probably correlate with the deities from Zoroastrianism (basically a duotheist religion if you've never heard of it).

Comment: Interesting point, John. I was unaware of any direct connection with any Ascended and Zoroaster. Anubis represents an ancient Egyptian god, Oma Desala is a literal translation of Mother Earth from Buddhism, the Ori and the Ancients embody various pagan characters (including Merlin and Morgan le Fay) and Orlin and the other ascended don't appear to have any special religious meaning. Can you give a specific example?

Comment: Also **Satan**, from Christian mythology.

Comment: Although in Sokar's case, it's not that he was the inspiration for the devil in Christianity on Earth, it's that he coopted the title from the humans he took off earth during the Medieval Ages.  Unlike most (all?) of the other instances, he's not the inspiration for it, just stealing some thunder.

Comment: There was also [Omoroca](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Omoroca) (of the Ohnes) who is identified with the Babylonian [Tiamat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiamat#As_Omoroca)

Comment: Hindi is a language, Hindu refers to something belonging to the religion Hinduism. It should be the latter. An edit suggestion is not working working because it's too short.

Comment: @talonx - The trick is to make a couple of other minor edits to bring the letter count up. For example, adding or removing some periods or commas.

Comment: Only just come across this Richard and it's a brilliant answer. Great info.

Comment: @CandiedMango - Glad you like it. It took a little while to put together.

Comment: Marduk should be in "Mesopotamian." Sumerian, IIRC. Certainly not Levantine. Also interested where you found the translation of Oma Desala (searching for this info is how I came upon the page). I had found that Oma is used to mean "grandma" in parts of England with heavy Germanic roots, but couldn't find anything on "Desala."

Comment: @RubelliteFae - Good finds. See edit.

Comment: There were also the shapeshifters of PXY-887 appearing to the transplanted humans as animal spirits (T'akaya, Xe'ls) from their traditional Salish (Native American) culture.

Answer (score 15):

The Goa'uld have actually impersonated gods from various mythologies. For example Ba'al was a Caananite deity, Cronus was the father of Zeus in the Greek mythology, and Nirrti was a Hindu goddess.

See [Goa'uld  Characters in Stargate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goa%27uld_characters_in_Stargate).